# How to use a model in another model with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#

The idea is a room with furniture in it. Something very simple. This is the Furni Model:

```
public class Furni
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class FurniDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Furni> Furniture { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine, of course. It is coupled to a table like it should be. Now i am writing the Room Model:

```
public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Furni Furni { get; set; } <<<<< I have no idea how to couple it to FurniDbContext
}
public class RoomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Any help? :) I hope i have been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate `DbContext` for each class.  It would look something like this:

**Room**

```
public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Furni Furniture { get; set; } // virtual is for lazy loading
}
```

**Furniture**

```
public class Furni
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }  // if you want to have the relationship both ways
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Furni> Furniture { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you mmillican, but it still doesn't work. Perhaps i should make myself more clear: I let Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web autogenerate a Controller for me, with Entity Framework, like i Always do. This Controller is a Controller tied to the Room Model. When i click Create in the browser, there are no form fields to fill in. I guess it does not recognize Furni as a datatype, since i can see form fields that are 'normal datatypes', like strings. What is want is, that if i enter something in the furni field, that my room model automaticly adds a furni object to the db.

Comment: To make myself even more clear: It is the Foreign Key idea i want. If my Room Controller adds a new room to the Rooms DbSet, with the ID and the Furni, i want it to automaticly add a Furni to the Furniture DbSet.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for cascading and using custom EditorTemplates.

Comment: How are you managing the rooms/furniture in the UI?  It's unclear.  Are you adding multiple rooms once you create a piece of furniture?

Comment: I create a room (1 room at a time) with a simple form, where i can define it's name etc. I can also define it's furniture. If i add a furniture to that room, that furniture should be automaticly addded to the furni dbSet. That is what i want :)